# Higher ranked trait bounds and function parameters

Tags: rust, higher-rank-types, bevy

I'm trying to understand the implementation of Bevy's [`IntoForEachSystem` trait](https://docs.rs/bevy_ecs/0.1.3/bevy_ecs/trait.IntoForEachSystem.html) and the way it interacts with the underlying Hecs [`Query` and `Fetch` traits](https://docs.rs/hecs/0.2.14/hecs/trait.Query.html). Hecs has query types (the thing you request in a call to `query::<T>`) and item types (the thing returned by the query). The idea is that `IntoForEachSystem` is implemented for closures whose query type matches the query's item type, and `fn f(&i32)` works because an `&i32` query returns an `&i32` item.

I think I extracted the relevant parts of the design in [this snippet](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=77e6aa351e49591edcc2e81dc771e9c8), but I can't make it type check:

```rust
// Hecs Query trait
trait Query {
    type Fetch: for<'a> Fetch<'a>;
}

// Hecs Query trait implementation for read-only references
impl<'a, T> Query for &'a T
where
    T: 'static,
{
    type Fetch = FetchRead<T>;
}

// Hecs Fetch trait
trait Fetch<'a>: Sized {
    type Item;
}

// Hecs Fetch trait implementation for read-only references
struct FetchRead<T>(std::marker::PhantomData<T>);

impl<'a, T> Fetch<'a> for FetchRead<T>
where
    T: 'static,
{
    type Item = &'a T;
}

// Bevy IntoForEachSystem trait, simplified
trait IntoForEachSystem<R> {
    fn system(self);
}

// Bevy IntoForEachSystem trait implementation for functions of one argument
impl<F, R> IntoForEachSystem<R> for F
where
    F: Fn(R),
    F: Fn(<<R as Query>::Fetch as Fetch>::Item),
    R: Query,
{
    fn system(self) {
        println!("hello");
    }
}

fn hmm(_x: &i32) {
    todo!()
}

fn main() {
    IntoForEachSystem::system(hmm)
}
```

Errors:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
   |
31 |     fn system(self);
   |     ---------------- required by `IntoForEachSystem::system`
...
46 | fn hmm(_x: &i32) {
   | ---------------- found signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r i32) -> _`
...
51 |     IntoForEachSystem::system(hmm)
   |                               ^^^ expected signature of `for<'r> fn(<FetchRead<i32> as Fetch<'r>>::Item) -> _`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoForEachSystem<&i32>` for `for<'r> fn(&'r i32) {hmm}`
```

I think the compiler is seeing the inferred lifetime `'r` in `fn hmm<'r>(&'r i32)` as being different from the forall lifetime `'a` in `type Fetch: for<'a> Fetch<'a>`. I don't see the trick that Bevy is using to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually super close!

```
fn main() {
    hmm.system();
}
```

This is ... very frustrating because `IntoForEachSystem::system(hmm)` should be equivalent to `hmm.system()` as far as I'm concerned. Maybe it's a bug in the Rust compiler?

Comment: Well that's weird. Indeed that's what the real code does in Bevy. I only changed it to UFCS to make the error messages clearer...